# Флоу разработки Ethereum Classic

Tags: ethereum

Есть задача по Ethereum Classic, сделать бота и ф-л обслуживания кошельков (создание, хранение, переводы). И дело в том что в крипте знаний нету и по этому сложно разобраться что делать.
Насколько я понимаю мне нужно создать ноду и вклиниться во всю экосистему эфира. Я пробовал ставить Geth, что то куда то подключился, создал какой то аккаунт, а дальше тьма. Читал доки и практически нигде нету и слова о кошельке, поэтому попал в тупик.

Если кто в курсе опишите пожалуйста последовательность действий, тоесть что зачем изучить и чем пользоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен кошелек собственно эфиров, то надо читать про работу с аккаунтами и "простыми" транзакциями (без передачи данных). Если кошельки для токенов - это уже работа со смарт-контрактами, там всё несколько сложнее - можно прочитать для начала про стандарт ERC20. Обязательно - про внешнюю подпись.